Clickhouse create from select set the value to 0 when given null for a nullable(Int8) column
I am trying to create a table in ClickHouse with the following SQL
CREATE TABLE stage.test_int_null (
    is_active Nullable(Int8),
    name String
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (tuple()) AS
select null as is_active,
    'test' as name

I expected the table should be:



is_active
name




null
test



Actually I got



is_active
name




0
test



I checked the doc and cannot find why is_acitve is set to 0 rather than null. Any suggestion?
Update: Not a Clickhouse issue, it is Metabase WebUI that displays it to 0.


It doesn't appear in the latest version, should be fixed now. Test here, where you can check with different versions.

My fault, it is null. It is displayed as 0 in Metabase WebUI.
